# Make bound element appear when populated after initial page load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the [linked JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkyor5tu/3/), I have a list of 2 contact objects, and a null active_contact object when the page loads.  When clicking on the "Make Active" link under a contact listing, I want that contact's properties to populate the active contact input fields.  Currently, my function to populate the active_contact object is firing, and the value is populated as expected, but it is not showing on the page (when inspecting element, the input fields do not even show in the code).

It is worth mentioning this is my first time using Knockout, so it is entirely possible I am missing something very basic.

The code:

HTML

```js
var initialData = [
    { firstName: "Danny", lastName: "LaRusso", phones: [
        { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 121-2121" },
        { type: "Home", number: "(555) 123-4567"}]
    },
    { firstName: "Sensei", lastName: "Miyagi", phones: [
        { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 444-2222" },
        { type: "Home", number: "(555) 999-1212"}]
    }
];
 
var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
        return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones) };
    }));
    
    self.active_contact = ko.observable();
 
    self.makeActive = function(firstName){
        for(var i in self.contacts()){
   if(self.contacts()[i].firstName == this.firstName){
                console.log(self.contacts()[i]);
     self.active_contact = self.contacts()[i];
   }
  }
    }
 
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

```html
 

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class='liveExample'> 
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <div id='contactsList'>
        <h3>active contact: </h3>
        <div class="active" data-bind="with: active_contact">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" />
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" />
        </div>
        <table class='contactsEditor'>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Phone numbers</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
                        <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.makeActive'>Make Active</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                                    <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in `self.makeActive`:

`.makeActive` does not receive a `firstname`, it really receives the full `contact` object - so the whole `for` loop is not necessary, since you already have what you are looking for.

The main issue is on this line:

```
self.active_contact = self.contacts()[i];
```

You are not assigning a new value to the observable, but are really *replacing* the observable itself. This is why your markup does not update anymore - the observable it was originally bound to is now gone.

Try this instead:

```
self.makeActive = function (contact) {
  self.active_contact(contact);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/dsqo3mnw/

First, I changed this:

```
self.active_contact = self.contacts()[i];
```

to this:

```
var activeContact = self.contacts()[i];
self.active_contact(activeContact.firstName + " " + activeContact.lastName);
```

I'm new to knockout as well, but this is my understanding: `active_contact` isn't a string object; it's a knockout observable function. To change its value, you have to invoke that function and pass in the new value.

Second, I changed your data binding from this:

```
<div class="active" data-bind="with: active_contact">
    <div data-bind="text: firstName"></div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold">
    Modified Active Contact Binding: 
    <span data-bind="text: active_contact"></span>
</p>
```

I'm not familiar with the `with` binding yet, but the `text` binding should suit your needs just fine, no?

Comment: Thanks for your response Nick, that does solve the problem as I presented it, but I outsmarted myself when writing the question.  I adapted an example from the knockout documentation to isolate this specific issue.  In my actual application, I need to populate multiple multiple form fields based on various properties of the selected object.  Will edit the question.